# Select row after each condition from the same table myql

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, sql-timestamp

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logging` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `logging` (`id`, `status`, `timestamp`) VALUES
  ('1', 'logout', '2021-01-01 05:01:00'),
  ('2', 'login', '2021-01-01 06:02:00'),
  ('3', 'online', '2021-01-01 06:03:00'),
  ('4', 'away', '2021-01-01 06:04:00'),
  ('5', 'online', '2021-01-01 06:05:00'),
  ('6', 'logout', '2021-01-02 04:00:00'),
  ('7', 'login', '2021-01-02 04:05:00'),
  ('8', 'online', '2021-01-02 04:07:00'),
  ('9', 'logout', '2021-01-02 04:55:00');
```

| id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | logout | 2021-01-01 05:01:00 |
| 2 | login | 2021-01-01 06:02:00 |
| 3 | online | 2021-01-01 06:03:00 |
| 4 | away | 2021-01-01 06:04:00 |
| 5 | online | 2021-01-01 06:05:00 |
| 6 | logout | 2021-01-02 04:00:00 |
| 7 | login | 2021-01-02 04:05:00 |
| 8 | online | 2021-01-02 04:07:00 |
| 9 | logout | 2021-01-02 04:55:00 |

i want to have an output:

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-01 06:03:00 | 2021-01-02 04:00:00 |
| 2021-01-02 | ... | ... |
| 2021-01-03 | ... | ... |

the rule is, 1 log day is from 5:00:00 - (next day) 04:49:49.
'A' is timestamp start from the first online (after login), 'B' is timestamp from the first logout (after online).

currently i'm using this query to apply the log day rule:

```
select dt, timestamp from ( 
    select id, left(timestamp, 10) dt, timestamp, status
    from logging
    where TIME(timestamp)  >= '05:00:00' and status = 'online'
    union all 
    select id, left((timestamp-interval 1 day), 10) dt ,timestamp, status
    from logging
    where TIME(timestamp)  < '05:00:00' and status = 'online'
    ) x group by dt;
```

But i have problem to apply the second rule to get the timestamp..

Updated:
Here's the test data and table: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tDJL2JHwbtSNEurrLEj11r/0
or http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aadb80/2

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry, I just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT t1.ts A, t3.ts B
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.ts < t2.ts
JOIN test t3 ON t2.ts < t3.ts
WHERE t1.status = 'login'
  AND t2.status = 'online'
  AND t3.status = 'logout'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t4
                   WHERE t1.ts < t4.ts
                     AND t4.ts < t2.ts
                     AND t4.status IN ('login', 'online', 'logout') )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t5
                   WHERE t2.ts < t5.ts
                     AND t5.ts < t3.ts
                     AND t5.status IN ('login', 'logout') )
  AND DATE(t1.ts - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) = DATE(t3.ts - INTERVAL '04:49:49' HOUR_SECOND);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94aafc96ba320d8faad6d9ba17e18752)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer solved my problem. But unfortunately, the rule has changed. So, I open a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450862/mysql-select-after-row-on-specific-rules