# MySQL select after row on specific rules

Tags: mysql, datetime, join, sql-timestamp

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logging` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `logging` (`id`, `status`, `timestamp`) VALUES
  ('1', 'logout', '2021-01-01 05:01:00'),
  ('2', 'login', '2021-01-01 06:02:00'),
  ('3', 'online', '2021-01-01 06:03:00'),
  ('4', 'away', '2021-01-01 06:04:00'),
  ('5', 'online', '2021-01-01 06:05:00'),
  ('6', 'logout', '2021-01-02 04:00:00'),
  ('7', 'login', '2021-01-02 04:05:00'),
  ('8', 'online', '2021-01-02 04:07:00'),
  ('9', 'away', '2021-01-02 04:08:00'),
  ('10', 'break', '2021-01-02 04:10:00'),
  ('11', 'online', '2021-01-02 04:15:00'),
  ('12', 'logout', '2021-01-02 04:55:00'),
  ('13', 'login', '2021-01-02 05:04:00'),
  ('14', 'online', '2021-01-02 05:05:00'),
  ('15', 'away', '2021-01-03 05:01:00'),
  ('16', 'logout', '2021-01-03 05:02:00'),
  ('17', 'login', '2021-01-03 05:04:00'),
  ('18', 'online', '2021-01-03 05:05:00'),
  ('19', 'logout', '2021-01-04 03:05:00'),
  ('20', 'login', '2021-01-04 05:07:00'),
  ('21', 'online', '2021-01-04 06:00:00'),
  ('22', 'logout', '2021-01-05 10:00:00'),
  ('23', 'login', '2021-01-05 11:00:00'),
  ('24', 'away', '2021-01-05 11:01:00'),
  ('25', 'online', '2021-01-06 06:01:00'),
  ('26', 'login', '2021-01-07 06:01:00'),
  ('26', 'logout', '2021-01-07 07:01:00');
```

| id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | logout | 2021-01-01 05:01:00 |
| 2 | login | 2021-01-01 06:02:00 |
| 3 | online | 2021-01-01 06:03:00 |
| 4 | away | 2021-01-01 06:04:00 |
| 5 | online | 2021-01-01 06:05:00 |
| 6 | logout | 2021-01-02 04:00:00 |
| 7 | login | 2021-01-02 04:05:00 |
| 8 | online | 2021-01-02 04:07:00 |
| 9 | logout | 2021-01-02 04:55:00 |

......

data provided on the insert query above.

i want to have an output:

| date | A (online) | B (Logout) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 04:07:00 | 2021-01-02 04:55:00 |
| 2021-01-02 | 2021-01-02 05:05:00 | 2021-01-03 04:59:59 |
| 2021-01-03 | 2021-01-03 05:05:00 | 2021-01-04 03:05:00 |
| 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 06:00:00 | 2021-01-04 04:59:59 |
| 2021-01-05 | 2021-01-04 05:00:00 | 2021-01-05 10:00:00 |
| 2021-01-06 | 2021-01-04 11:00:00 | 2021-01-06 04:59:59 |

the rule is, 1 log day is from 5:00:00 - (next day) 04:59:59.
'A' is timestamp start from the last online (after login, if any), 'B' is timestamp from the last logout (**if there is no logout, B set to 04:59:59**.
Another rule is, when the last day doesnt have 'logout' after 'online', it's counted to the next log day (**the next log day set to be 05.00.00 if the last record from the last log day is 'online'**)

currently i'm using this query to apply the log day rule:

```
SELECT date(t1.timestamp) dt, (t2.timestamp) A, (t3.timestamp) B, t1.status, t2.status, t3.status
FROM logging t1
JOIN logging t2 ON t1.timestamp < t2.timestamp
JOIN logging t3 ON t2.timestamp < t3.timestamp
WHERE 
t1.status = 'login'
AND t2.status = 'online'
AND t3.status = 'logout'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM loggingt4
               WHERE t1.timestamp < t4.timestamp
                 AND t4.timestamp < t2.timestamp
                 AND t4.status IN ('login', 'online', 'logout') )
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM logging t5
               WHERE t2.timestamp < t5.timestamp
                 AND t5.timestamp < t3.timestamp
                 AND t5.status IN ('login', 'logout'))
AND DATE(t1.timestamp - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) = DATE(t3.timestamp - INTERVAL '05:59:59' HOUR_SECOND);
```

Comment: ah yes, i mean 04:59:59 @Akina

Comment: *i want to have an output:* The values in desired output are absent in source data.

Comment: sorry my bad.. i just updated the source data @Akina

Comment: Why the session from `'2021-01-01 06:02:00'` till `'2021-01-02 04:00:00'` is not listed in desired output? Please verify your question and all values in it carefully, then post. No need to rush. PS. What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: it's not counted cause I want only to count the last 'online' after the last 'login' (if any), so the desired output is as mentioned in the table. and if there's no login in 1 log day, so it's set to be 5:00:00 if the last day has an 'online' row, but if it's not, then counted the first 'online' in that log day.. I'm using MySQL version 5.7.24. Thanks in advance @Akina and  yeah, i just added new source data, sorry for my rush

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cf282226e47ee48ddf536b65d83c8b2, intermediate SELECT. I see 4 sessions login-online-logout (some of them with 2 online rows). Maybe 3rd (from login of 2021-01-02 05:04:00 till logout of 2021-01-03 05:02:00) must be divided because it crosses the border of 05:00. Why only 3 rows is shown in your desired output?

Comment: yes, the desired output has only 3 rows because it only counts the last session of login-online-logout. and it might have some 2 online rows (from the intermediate select) because after 'online' then the next record could be 'away' then going back to 'online'.. in that case (if theres 2 rows of online, i want to pick the first one) @Akina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
SELECT DATE(t1.`timestamp` - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) `date`,
       MAX(t1.`timestamp`) login, 
       MAX(t2.`timestamp`) online, 
       MAX(t3.`timestamp`) logout
FROM logging t1
JOIN logging t2 ON t1.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp`
JOIN logging t3 ON t2.`timestamp` < t3.`timestamp`
WHERE t1.status = 'login'
  AND t2.status = 'online'
  AND t3.status = 'logout'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM logging t4
                   WHERE t1.`timestamp` < t4.`timestamp`
                     AND t4.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp`
                     AND t4.status IN ('login', 'online', 'logout') )
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM logging t5
                   WHERE t2.`timestamp` < t5.`timestamp`
                     AND t5.`timestamp` < t3.`timestamp`
                     AND t5.status IN ('login', 'logout') )
GROUP BY `date`
)
SELECT `date`,
       online,
       CASE WHEN DATE(online - INTERVAL 5 HOUR) = DATE(logout - INTERVAL '04:59:59' HOUR_SECOND)
            THEN logout
            ELSE DATE(online + INTERVAL 19 HOUR) + INTERVAL '04:59:59' HOUR_SECOND
            END logout
FROM cte
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=db67897b38401b51ee342453494922fb)

CTE is used for visibility only - you may combine everything into one query.

Comment: Thank youuu, I've checked it, almost perfect to solve my case, there's one problem left.. how to continue the logging to next day? i mean as i mentioned earlier, if user stay online and cross the time border then logout at 5.02, i want to log the next day log to 5:00:00-05:02:00. this is counted if only the last log day is 'online'..

Comment: @DianAriefRisdianto *there's one problem left.. how to continue the logging to next day?* Formally the session may be divided to 2, 3 and more parts, is it? Look at the normalizing outer query... it uses simple normalizing. Create recursive CTE which divides the session, extracts normalized part for current day and calculates the tail (which will be saved or divided on the next iteration). And decide what must be used as a start for the tail - maybe 05:00?

Comment: and also if login happens in the previous log day (2021-01-03 04:44:00) then online in the next day (2021-01-03 05:02:00)- logout at 2021-01-03 07:00:00, then i want to count the 'online' even if there's no 'login' before so the ouput i want should be: 2021-01-03 05:02:00 to 2021-01-03 07:00:00

Comment: sounds simple, I've tried and done to divide each session but still find it difficult to get the right query to extract normalized current day and the tail.. can you explain by writing it in a query?

Comment: @DianAriefRisdianto Please look at [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=43fd4557489898b320ea5e645f276d86), add desired output as a comment with some explanations and provide new link.

Comment: thank you for helping me, how to normalize the online to 05:00:00 and continue it to the next day if there's no logout, it still confuses me hehehe sorry I'm kinda new to database, i just updated the data source and the desired output in the question.. can please help me once again?

Comment: @DianAriefRisdianto You're the only who can solve this. Think what output must be obtained for the source data by the link.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer tho, but after all, I decided to create a helper table to make this happen haha.

Comment: @DianAriefRisdianto This is only your business how to use the answer. If it helps even a little, this is enough. *I decided to create a helper table* Watch/check carefully for data consistency/validity/correctness - this is a problem of any overdefined data.